# VM bitnami magento 2.4.2 stack

Tags: magento2, linux

How do I access the magento files in a VM running the bitnami magento stack?

192.168.1.12/magento ?

When I do that get connection refused, but I could be wrong about how to run magento for the first time. Maybe I should run a script to setup magento? myphphadmin works, also I get,

It works! when I browse to 192.168.1.12

so I know the web server is running.

Has anyone else used this stack?

Its possible I have screwed up something and it should be accessed through 192.168.1.12/magento but I am just not sure.

This may not be the appropriate place to post this question, if so I apologize in advance.

Thanks for any help you can offer. Have a great day everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a small number of people in Magento community using VM Bitnami to setup/develop Magento locally. Almost people use **docker** for Magento development environment, so I strongly recommend you use docker, and then use one of 2 docker configurations below as they are the best and the most popular docker configurations for Magento 2.

- Docker-magento by MarkShust https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento
- Warden by David Alger https://warden.dev/

Their document is great and easy to follow:

For Markshust's docker-magento, you can go to the github repository I mentioned above to get the document to setup `docker-magento` environment and Magento 2. He also provides a free screencast course which details the basic usage of his docker-magento in his repository.

For Warden, you should install Warden https://docs.warden.dev/installing.html, then install Magento 2: https://docs.warden.dev/environments/magento2.html

PS 1: Magento 2.4.2 is old, you should upgrade your site to 2.4.4-p2 or 2.4.5-p1 asap to keep your site safe.

PS 2: This community (Magento Stack Exchange) is the right place for your question, so if you had any issues/questions related to Magento, you can post them here.

Comment: Hi Tu, I will check that out, not sure about Docker I have never used it. Thanks for your advice, I will check the links you have posted, thank you for taking the time to answer. James in Canada

Comment: Hi James, if you faced any issues, feel free to let me know. I'm glad to help you.